# More concise $f(x) = (\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(20)-10)\times 10^{\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(2x)-x}$?

Tags: functions, random-functions

Assume a typical (I think) PRNG $\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(n) = \omega$ where $\{\; \omega \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < \omega \le n \;\}$ for $n > 0$.

I want to create a random function $f(x)$, such that $f(x) = y$ is a real number within $\pm 9.9\bar{9} \times 10^{\pm x}$ and, crucially, $\lfloor \log _{10} f(x) \rfloor$ is a random integer within $\pm x$.

Perhaps more accurately,[2] if we write $f(x) = y$ as $f(x) = a \times 10^b$,[1] then $\{-x \le b \le x \}$, and all $b$ within that range are equally likely, for a given $x$.

The results needn't stand up to rigorous statistical scrutiny. Since I don't know what kind of answers (if any!) this question will get, hopefully it's enough to say, "the fairer the distribution, the better".

### My best attempt

The following seems to produce reasonable results, although I hope this can be improved to something more concise, ideally with only one $\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(n)$.

$f(x) = (\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(20)-10)\times 10^{\mathop{\mathrm{rand}}(2x)-x}$

### Non-decimal radix

Although my question is specific to base-10, general solutions for any arbitrary radix would be welcome as well.

---

1. Normal scientific notation, i.e., $\{ -10 < a < 10 \}$
2. My math is quite rusty. I will accept any edits to improve the language/notation in my question.